# Understanding a summation notation. Sum(j=2 to n) j - 1

Tags: algorithm-analysis, summation

I have been reading analysis of insertion sort in the "Introduction to algorithms" and faced a problem with understanding a specific summation notation when the worst case occurs.

I know how one can get formula for arithmetic series when we deal with **while loop header**, I mean 2+3+...+n equals to (n*(n+1) / 2) - 1. But what I do not understand is how one can get formula for **while loop body**:

[image: summation notation on page 27]

It is obvious, that we execute while loop body one time less, than while loop header, because of the final conditional test. Hence, we should subtract one. But how do we get n * (n - 1) / 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=2}^n \left(j - 1\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i$$

Comment: Alternatively $\sum_{j=2}^n (j-1) = \sum_{j=2}^n j - \sum_{j=2}^n 1 = n(n+1)/2 - 1 - (n-1) = n(n-1) / 2$.

Comment: Thank you, Stef and Pseudonym. Yes, both statements make sense to me, since we are subtracting one n times from index two.